# Install4j: How to prevent file overwrites when using 'Add VM options' installation action?

Tags: java, install4j

We are using some calculations with 'Add VM options' installer actions. Now every time we update our system using the installer all user changes in  '*.vmoptions' files are lost. Is there a good way to prevent it?

NB: We considered to use a 'Condition expression' to check if the *vmoptions* file is already present but have not found a way to determine proper filename because it is computed internally based on Launcher's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your condition expression to

```
new File(context.getLauncherById("123").getRelativeFileName().
    replaceAll(".exe", ".vmoptions")).exists()
```

then the action will only be executed if the .vmoptions file does not exist.